# How to set "selected networks" for Azure Key vault while creating using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I want to set the firewall status as "Selected Network" - basically deny all packets while I create an Azure Key vault service. (I have another automation to set the agreed firewall rules).

I am deploying the ARM template and using the below Property:

```
"networkAcls": {
          "value": {
            "defaultAction": "Deny",
            "bypass": "AzureServices"
          }
        }
```

However this is not working.

Current Result:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: You can enable the key vault log to check if it really does not work. And what action have you done when you say it does not work? Also, which document do you follow to set the firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the template i tried for Network ACL which worked for me, I have not added Value node in the template.

```
"networkAcls": {
      "bypass": "string",
      "defaultAction": "string",
      "ipRules": [
        {
          "value": "string"
        }
      ],
      "virtualNetworkRules": [
        {
          "id": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2018-02-14/vaults

try and see if it works for you.

Comment: I used the same code that I was using and it worked this time. I do not know why it was not working for me earlier. I was referring to the same article that you mentioned in your answer.